# Applying Betweenness Centrality to a Large Matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I've created the following algorithm to calculate Betweenness Centrality of a network I made. The network is held in a large matrix 62589x62589.

```
getBetween<-function(matIn)
{
 betScore<-c()
 for(i in 1:nrow(matIn))
 {
  tmpTF<-(matIn[i, ] !=0)
  tmp1<-matIn[i, tmpTF]
  mat2<-matrix(0, length(tmp1), length(tmp1))
  rownames(mat2)<-rownames(matIn)[tmpTF]
  colnames(mat2)<-rownames(matIn)[tmpTF]
  for(j in 1:nrow(mat2))
  {
   for(k in 1:ncol(mat2))
   {
    if(mat2[j,k] > matIn[rownames(mat2)[j], colnames(mat2)[k]])
    {
     mat2[j,k] <-0
    }
   }
  }    
  betScore<-c(betScore, sum(mat2 > 0))
 }
}
```

However, iterating over ~4Billion values is extremely inefficient. I couldn't find any packages after a quick search that would calculate betweenness centrality, does anyone know of any. Also, could anyone give me any pointers on the implementation of my algorithm and how it could be improved?

Thanks

Comment: Your function is missing a return value. It also gives an error when tested with `set.seed(42); mat <- matrix(sample(0:5,100,TRUE),1)`. Please fix your function, provide input data and describe the algorithm. Maybe function `betweeness` from package sna provides what you need?

Comment: There is another `betweenness` function in `igraph`, and in several other packages: 
`library(sos); ???betweenness`.